# Problems installing symfony 2.5 on a vagrant box

Tags: php, symfony, vagrant, composer-php

Can't install a fresh copy of symfony 2.5.0 in my "hashicorp/precise64" vagrant box.

Using

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition temp/ 2.5.0 -vvv
```

to install. It always stops at

```
...
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$serializer.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bridge.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$twig-bundle.json from cache
Reading /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$web-profiler-bundle.json from cache
```

My Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8088
end
```

Comment: Remove the cache (rm -rf /home/vagrant/.composer/cache/), update composer (composer self-update), and try again.

Comment: You might want to consider having your codebase not stored on the VM. A VM, especially one created by Vagrant is intended to be disposable. By putting your code on there you're making it a lot less disposable.

Comment: @Seer I use Windows 7 as a code-host, and vagrant just mounts a shared folder to /vagrant. I just use composer in my box because I have no php/apache etc. installed on my Windows-Machine

Comment: @JakubZalas Already tried both. No result.

Comment: Are you certain the VM has internet access? Are you sure the VM has enough hard drive space? Are there any actual errors produced by this, or does it just halt?

Comment: Anyone?

My `composer update some/package` hangs on `Reading /Users/alan/.composer/cache/repo/https---packagist.org/provider-symfony$web-profiler-bundle.json from cache` too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying it again and forget about it for half an hour it succeeded. It was just damn slow. Normally 10-20 seconds